# Exchanging data from web

Tags: java, android

I am creating a program which calculates the solar radiations received on earth. The program is complete and working. I have made it specifically for my city, but I want to generalize it for the whole world. Only one thing is standing between me and my goal:

```
double Hm[] = {
  4.38, 5.18, 5.93, 6.65, 6.67, 6.40, 5.44, 5.27, 5.62, 5.24, 4.5, 4.11
};
```

This data is the only thing I want to generalize. These values are for my city only. I want to take Longitude and Latitude as an input and then this input goes to the NASA website, extract only the data I want and return those values in an array as shown above. How can I do that?

Comment: You figure. We'll help when there are *specific* problems (implementation) along the way.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I think we need a little more info. Is there a specific web service that you want to be able to talk to in Java? And could you describe the transaction in more detail? (ie. get the data from this url, crunch the numbers in the program you already have working, send data to this url, etc) If you provide us a little more info I'm sure someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) for getting location.
You can send Lat Lon you got to your web service you can take responce in something like `JSON`

Comment: Plus one for you, I had trouble understanding exactly what the OP was asking, but this seems to address it really well--I think ;)